# Help identifying a low resolution kanji

Tags: kanji, writing-identification

I am making captions in Japanese for a song. I have a kanji that I can't identify because of the low resolution and writing, could you help?

The kanji:

[image]

The context:

[image]

The most resembling one that I found is "淦" but I don't think that is right.

Comment: 滲, reading the sentence the verb にじむ comes to mind right away regardless of how well the details of the kanji can be seen.

Comment: For the future though, you can use image lighteners like [this one](https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/lightening.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [lyrics](https://w.atwiki.jp/hmiku/pages/13084.html), the line goes「鮮{あざ}やかな季節{きせつ}の涙{なみだ}で滲{にじ}ませて」.